# arabic_reshape on Android

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

arabic_reshaper working fine with windows and linux but when I run it as apk file in android, App crashed.
My errors is:

```
python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
python  :    File "/media/mehdi/2436ef15-26cf-4be8-9eed-6befb73eddd8/mehdi/Documents/BuildozerTest/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 18, in <module>
python  :    File "/media/mehdi/2436ef15-26cf-4be8-9eed-6befb73eddd8/mehdi/Documents/BuildozerTest/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/FinalAPP/arabic_reshaper/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
python  :  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/data/user/0/org.test.finalapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/arabic_reshaper/__version__.py'
python  : Python for android ended.
```

In line 18, imported arabic_reshaper

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I have the same problem. arabic_reshaper works in python but crashes in the android app. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the module as a requirement?
If you already did, the module may have compiled components and needs a recipe. Check [here](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes/)

Also try `buildozer android clean` if you are using buildozer.

Another workround that is not recommended, is to include the module in the same directory as your main.py.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I appended *Arabic-reshaper* to *.spec and I used buildozer. Thank you, I read "recipe", but I'm beginner so don't understand enough. I have written simple code,Now I don't know what name to put this file and where?

```
from pythonforandroid.recipe import PythonRecipe
class ArabicReshaperRecipe(PythonRecipe):
    url = 'https://github.com/mpcabd/python-arabic-reshaper/archive/master.zip'

    depends = ['python3', 'numpy','sys','unittest']

    site_packages_name = 'arabic_reshaper'

recipe = ArabicReshaperRecipe()
```